# How could i fix my Quaternion.LookRotation in 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

Im trying to make player look at my mouse in 2D top down shooter im trying to make. I haven't had any expierience with Quaternions yet, but i managed to fix the common problem of the object rotating. I have other problem, Player dosent point at mouse at all, it just points in some random direction.

```
Public Transform playerPos;
Private Vector3 mousePos;

// Define and look at mouse

 void MouseL()
{
    mousePos = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, 1);
    Vector3 relativePos = mousePos - playerPos.position;

// rotate relativePos so the player will not rotate 90 deg in y axis

    Vector3 rotatedRelativePos = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 90) * relativePos;
    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward, rotatedRelativePos);
    playerPos.rotation = rotation;


}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    MouseL();
}
```

Even if relativePos does change, the rotation of the player dosen't for some reason, regardles where i move with player, it seems only that when mousePos does change it rotates, but i put relativePos in the rotation so i don't know how it dosen't rotate when the rotatedRelativePos does change.

Edit: The rotations changes if relativePos changes, but very slightly, like 2 degrees across the whole screen.

Edit 2: managed to do it with this code:

```
Vector3 pz = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    pz.z = 0;
    var b = (pz.y - playerPos.position.y);
     var a = (pz.x - playerPos.position.x);
     var tang = a / b;
     var radianRotation = Mathf.Atan(tang);
     var degreeRotation = radianRotation * (180 / Mathf.PI);

    if (pz.y < playerPos.position.y)
    {
        playerPos.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, -degreeRotation + 180);
    }

    else { playerPos.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, -degreeRotation); }
```

Comment: Why not just use inverse tangent since it’s 2D? Then you have a rotation angle and that’s it

Comment: thanks, i did it, but i have the same problem,


`var a = Mathf.Abs(Input.mousePosition.y - playerPos.position.y);
        var b = Mathf.Abs(Input.mousePosition.x - playerPos.position.x);
        var tang = a / b;
        var radianRotation = Mathf.Atan(tang);
        var degreeRotation = radianRotation * (180 / Mathf.PI);
        
        playerPos.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, degreeRotation);`


let me know if there is something wrong with this

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure that your character moves in XY plane, not in XZ, which is default setup for unity 3D?
2. You are directly using mouse screen position as a world position, which is possible, only if your character located on a canvas in screen space - overlay mode (or very unusual manual setup), in other cases you need to convert screen to world poin. Your last updated sentence points on this problem, so, I think, this is the case.
3. What did th job for me:

Vector3 worldUp = Vector3.up; // You can set your world Up-axis there

```
Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
Plane plane = new Plane(worldUp, playerPos.position);
float enter;
if (plane.Raycast(ray, out enter))
{
    // next two lines does the same, so select one at your own:
    //playerPos.LookAt(ray.GetPoint(enter), worldUp);
    playerPos.forward = ray.GetPoint(enter) - playerPos.position;
}
```

In general, its way more convenient to operate with vectors, than quaternions, you just need to set transform`s local forward direction, which is equals to moustPointerPosition - playerPosition.

Comment: When i define worldUp as either Vector3.forward or back character rotates 90 degrees in y axis making it a very thin line. When i define it as Vector3.up at dosen't rotate at all.

Tried both the lines i could choose, same result

Comment: What if you try this one:      `Vector3 playerScreenPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(playerPos.position); 
Vector3 screenDirection = Input.mousePosition - playerScreenPos;
playerPos.forward = screenDirection;`

Comment: that ones even weirder. it rotates in both x and y axis to point its "upside" at the mouse

Comment: Ok. Can you please tell, which world axis is your "up", around which axis you want your character to rotate?

Comment: Then, please, try this code again - with added logs, and tell me, what output you have in the console:

Comment: `Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
Plane plane = new Plane(worldUp, playerPos.position);
float enter;
if (plane.Raycast(ray, out enter))
{
    // next two lines does the same, so select one at your own:
    //playerPos.LookAt(ray.GetPoint(enter), worldUp);
    playerPos.forward = ray.GetPoint(enter) - playerPos.position;
Debug.Log("Raycast done, enter: " + enter + " point " + ray.GetPoint(enter) + " player position " + playerPos.position + " result forward vector " + (ray.GetPoint(enter) - playerPos.position));
}
else
{
Debug.Log("Raycast failed");
}`

Comment: thanks for your help, but i managed to do it using the inverted tangents. but thank you.